# SQL * PLUS defining CONNECT_IDENTIFIER in glogin.sql file

Tags: database, shell, oracle11g, sqlplus

I am connecting to a remote ORACLE DB with SQL * PLUS. I use command line like this to achieve it:

```
sqlplus user/password@1.1.1.1/orcl
```

Is it posible to store login parameters in

> glogin.sql

file and just run command like:

```
sqlplus
```

?

It executes script in glogin.sql file automatically, but I have hard time setting login parameters there, ie:

```
USER="user";
PASSWORD="password";
SERVER_HOST="1.1.1.1";
SERVICE_NAME="orcl";
```

Comment: It's *possible*, but probably not wise. Why do you want to store login parameters in that site-wide file? Or even in your more personal login.sql file? Leaving plain credentials in a file doesn't seem like a good idea. You could use a `tnsnames.ora` file to record the server/port/service name so you can use a simpler alias; and maybe a wallet to store credentials if you really don't want to supply them each time?

Comment: Thanks for replying. At this moment I am exploring my options. Storing remote IP address and DB name in a `glogin.sql` file would already be a great improvement. I just don't know how to construct the file. I will explore `tnsnames.ora` too, thank you.

Answer (score 1):

As described [in the documentation](https://docs.oracle.com/cd/E11882_01/server.112/e16604/ch_two.htm#i1132910), `glogin.sql` is a site profile so you only want that to contain commands that apply for all users; but there is a `login.sql` user profile for commands specific to a single user.

Anyway, I thought this might be possible (but inadvisable) by having the following line at the start of your `login.sql`:

```
connect user/password@1.1.1.1:1521/orcl
```

and then launching SQL*Plus with:

```
sqlplus /nolog
```

but as the docs also say, the profile files are run when `/nolog` is used *and* after connection, so this just causes a loop:

```
$ sqlplus /nolog

SQL*Plus: Release 12.1.0.2.0 Production on Thu Aug 22 09:20:41 2019

Copyright (c) 1982, 2014, Oracle.  All rights reserved.

Connected.
Connected.
Connected.
Connected.
Connected.
Connected.
Connected.
Connected.
Connected.
Connected.
Connected.
Connected.
Connected.
Connected.
Connected.
Connected.
Connected.
Connected.
Connected.
SP2-0309: SQL*Plus command procedures may only be nested to a depth of 20.
Connected.
SP2-0309: SQL*Plus command procedures may only be nested to a depth of 20.
SP2-0309: SQL*Plus command procedures may only be nested to a depth of 20.
SQL>
```

You are actually connected successfully at that point:

```
...
Connected.
SP2-0309: SQL*Plus command procedures may only be nested to a depth of 20.
Connected.
SP2-0309: SQL*Plus command procedures may only be nested to a depth of 20.
SP2-0309: SQL*Plus command procedures may only be nested to a depth of 20.
SQL> select sysdate from dual;

SYSDATE
------------------
22-AUG-19

SQL>
```

but that is quite unpleasant.

A simpler alternative is to have a shell script wrapper around SQL*Plus, e.g. `sql.sh`:

```
USER="user";
PASSWORD="password";
SERVER_HOST="1.1.1.1";
SERVER_PORT="1521";
SERVICE_NAME="orcl";

/path/to/sqlplus ${USER}/${PASSWORD}@//${SERVER_HOST}:${SERVER_PORT}/${SERVICE_NAME}
```

and run that shell script instead.

But storing plain-text credentials in files is a bad idea, however well-protected you think the files are; and providing the password in the SQL*Plus command line means it is visible to other OS users via `ps`. You should at least remove the password from the script, which will prompt the user for that at login time. (Assuming the script will be run interactively, of course.)

You might also want to look at [Oracle Wallet](https://docs.oracle.com/en/database/oracle/oracle-database/12.2/dbimi/using-oracle-wallet-manager.html#GUID-AFC3BF3B-3669-40B9-A3B1-7356556B5CFC) - there's an overview [here](https://oracle-base.com/articles/10g/secure-external-password-store-10gr2).

And you could store the database settings - host, port and service name - in `tnsnames.ora` so you can connect more simply with a TNS alias (with or preferably without the password on the command line):

```
sqlplus user@my_alias
```

If you can't modify the global `tnsnames.ora` you can create your own version anywhere, and set the `TNS_ADMIN` environment variable to point to the directory that is in, so it picks up your file instead of the global one.

[Read more](https://docs.oracle.com/en/database/oracle/oracle-database/12.2/sqpug/SQL-Plus-quick-start.html#GUID-D65BD2EF-72C6-4E61-812B-9FFCAAF6F305).